# What is this handheld console/game?

Tags: game-identification, hardware-identification

I have no idea what these games are or if they have a console.

Does anyone know what these are? I don't see a company logo on them either.

[image: Image 1 - 4 cartridges]

[image: Image 2 - cartridge back]

Comment: Any chance we can get a less blurry and more up close picture?

Comment: Reminds me of my old R-Zone, that system also featured an LCD screen on each game cartridge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-Zone

Comment: "I have no idea what these games are or if they have a console." If they didn't have a console, how would you play the game?

Answer (score 57):

Searching for the phrase "Blue whale & battle boat", led me to [this hand held game](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/unusual-final-fantasy-viii-handheld-507893063):

[image]

The title on that page says it is: "Unusual FINAL FANTASY VIII Handheld Video 5 in 1 Game Mint Sealed In Package!"

The 4 pieces you see here are part of the screens that can be inserted into the main center to play the game on their title.

Further searching using the term "Final Fantasy VIII handheld" found more instances of it [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/i/232583316731?chn=ps), seems to be a one off handheld LCD game.

Comment: If you have to switch the screen to switch the game, they are probably not pixel-based screens but rather segmented LCDs. You can hold them at an angle to the light to see the segments.

Comment: Those are definitely segmented screens. Chinese manufacturers push dozens of those swappable-screen consoles with different brandings and molds - and it's likely that this one has nothing to do with Final Fantasy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBBMnY7mANg - Ashens' channel has quite a few reviews of those, and you can see that most of them recycle the same, or similar, set of games.

Comment: Basically these games are not worth the packaging they're in.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking at are games from a style of handheld console typically known as a pop station. The games are normally the same for each variation of the console and you switch them out by changing the display. The youtuber Ashens has a full series dedicated to these machines.